# Laravel 5.2 , why this route does not work

Tags: laravel-5

This route works fine :

```
Route::get('identite_personne/{id_personne?}', array('as' => 'getFormulaireIdentitePersonne','uses' => 'PersonnesController@getFormulaireIdentitePersonne'))->middleware('estAutoriseFonction:IDENTITE_PERSONNE');
```

And in my view I call this route like that :

```
<a href="{{ route('getFormulaireIdentitePersonne', ['id_personne' => $personne->id_personne]) }}" >{{ $personne->id_personne }}</a>
```

All works fine.

BUT : you see that the parameter {id_personne} is optional (there is a ? in the route).

And if I want that this parameter is mandatory, and I remove this ?, the route becomes :

```
Route::get('identite_personne/{id_personne}', array('as' => 'getFormulaireIdentitePersonne','uses' => 'PersonnesController@getFormulaireIdentitePersonne'))->middleware('estAutoriseFonction:IDENTITE_PERSONNE');
```

And in this case I have this error :

> Missing required parameters for [Route: getFormulaireIdentitePersonne] [URI: identite_personne/{id_personne}]

So my question : why this route works fine when the parameter is optional and does not work when this parameter is mandatory ?

Dominique

Comment: Is there any other place you use this route?

Comment: no , only in the view. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in calling , Try this:

```
Route::get('identite_personne/{id_personne?}', array('as' => 'identite_personne','uses' => 'PersonnesController@getFormulaireIdentitePersonne'))->middleware('estAutoriseFonction:IDENTITE_PERSONNE');

<a href="{!!url('identite_personne', [$personne->id_personne]) !!}" >{!! $personne->id_personne !!}</a>
```

Comment: I tried, and unfortunately, I still have the same error.

Comment: I've updated the answer , if still same error then problem is some where else.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Govind. but I tried a lot of things ,without success : always the same error "Missing required parameters". Certainly the error is somewhere else. But how to find it  ? For the moment this parameter is still optional on the route, it works like that. I will search later. thanks again. Dominique

Comment: Let me show your <a> link after render with optional parameter.

Comment: <a href="http://localhost/ecole/public/identite_personne/11046" >11046</a>. It seems normal.

Comment: I've updated my answer , Please try this. Its final from me :)

Comment: I give up for the moment, I will come back later, I have to advance in my project. thanks a lot Govind.